# apsheduler python is not running as scheduled

Tags: python, apscheduler

The job_function isnt getting executed even once, even when i waited for more than 10 mins.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import send_mail


def job_function():
    print("Hello World")

    send_mail('abc@test.com')

sched = BackgroundScheduler()

sched.add_job(job_function, 'interval', minutes=1)

sched.start()
```

Comment: Describe your issue in the question itself by editing not in comments.

Comment: I waited for around 5 mins, but the called function isnt getting executed, if i call the function outside the job_function , it executes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this code, and this code only, the problem looks like that your program terminates before the time limit is reached.

Try adding this infinite loop at the end of your program which will prevent it to quit:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1000)
```

Then terminate your program with CTRL+C.

Comment: Its executing now with while True loop, but once i do Ctrl+C the process gets terminated. I think I have to run the python command with nohup. But whats the point of using BackgroundScheduler() module from this library, it doesnt make sense if i have to run the process with while True loop and explicitly run it as a background process myself.

Comment: You are confusing background thread vs. background process. apscheduler is in-process scheduler for tasks for your application. If you do not want to spawn the process tha manages background task threads for you, you need to look either Huey or Celery. You did not explain your use case in your question why are you doing this, so it is not possible to tell what would be the best approach.

Comment: I want a simple scheduler to send mail every day once

Comment: The simplest one is that you use OS scheduler (Cron on UNIX, Windows thing on Windows) to execute a script once in a day